# TypeScript error - property 'xyz' does not exist on type { }

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have a simple JavaScript function (in a .tsx file)

```js
export async function addDealer(payload: object) {
  let tempSupplierId = "cc9cfc30-5c01-11ec-bf63-0242ac130002"
  let addDealerURL = URLMap("addDealerAPI")
  addDealerURL = addDealerURL.replace("{supplierId}", tempSupplierId)
  let result = {}
  try {
    result.data = await fetch(addDealerURL, { //line 39
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    })
  } catch (e) {
    result.error = e  //line 47
  }
  return result;
}
```

It gives compile errors like
`property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'` and
`property 'error' does not exist on type '{}'` due to lines 39 and 47. This is a valid code in plain JavaScript, but TypeScript won't allow because result - {}.

I understand these are valid errors and why they are appearing. I just don't know how to solve these.

I tried defining a type at the top of the file as below:

```
type resultType = {
  data: any;
  error: any;
}
```

And in the function, defined a result as resultType.

```
  let result: resultType
```

With this change I get new errors as:

> Variable 'result' is used before being assigned.

I am confused with TypeScript, as I am still getting acquanted with it.

Comment: *"With this change I get new errors as: Variable 'result' is used before being assigned."* You wouldn't get that if you just made those changes to the code shown. Please show the changed code you got that error from.

Comment: But separately, that type doesn't match what you're doing with `result`. If you're assigning `{}` to `result`, then it can't have any non-optional properties, since `{}` doesn't have any properties. You'd need `type ResultType = { data?: any; error?: any };` But if you're going to make properties optional and give them the type `any`, there's really not much point in using TypeScript.

Comment: Try with `let result: resultType = { data: null, error: null }`, or better yet `type resultType = { data?: any; error?: any; }` and `let result: resultType = {}` if the rest of the code allows you to.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right.  I am planning to store the response that comes from an  api, into the data variable.  If response doesn't come, and error comes, I plan to store the error in error variable.   The error goes away with the suggested changes by you and Caramiriel.

I am an infant in the typescript world, so I obviously do not understand many things and best practices.

Comment: May be I should use a union type here?